# Invoke ADF pipeline using Azure EventHubs

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-data-factory

Would like to know whether we can invoke ADF pipeline using Azure EventHub?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean that a given message should trigger an ADF pipeline? I am not sure what you expect..

Comment: Hi,any progress?Does my answer helps you?

Comment: Yes Jay, got the pointer which i was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Event Hub Trigger Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs) to listen your event hub service. It 
 will be run whenever an event hub receives a new event.

[image]

In the function method, please use [ADF sdk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-dot-net#create-a-pipeline-run) to invoke your ADF pipeline.

Comment: So this answer suggests to use an Azure function to bridge the event hub and the data factory? Isnt there a way to do it directly?